# java MVC input type date not accessable

Tags: java, model-view-controller

my Servlet Controller works fine when performing "request.getParameter(...) for all 
of my inputs expect when i am trying to get an input of type "date". Then its not able to set a date neither to get(returns null)

This ist the codeim my html document:

```
 <input type="date" name="bday" value="{{bday}}">
```

and this is the doPost method of my Controller :

```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
    String bdayDate= (req.getParameter("bday"));    
    Console.log("Request get Parameter as String-> bDate: "+bdayDate);
    }
}
```

I hope someone has an idea what could be the problem.